# Rsync on Windows: wrong permissions for created directories

Tags: windows, rsync

I'm trying to push changes to my server through ssh on windows (cygwin) using `rsync`.
The command I am using is:

> rsync -rvz -e ssh /cygdrive/c/myfolder/ rsyncuser@192.168.1.110:/srv/www/prj112/myfolder/

`/srv/www/prj112/myfolder/` is owned by `rsyncuser`. My problem is that eventhough with `rsync` the sub directories are create as they publish, each directory is assigned default permission of `d---------` so `rsync` fails to copy any files inside it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you post your Windows and Cygwin versions along with the output of the following command: ls -la /srv/www/prj112/myfolder?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The option to ignore NTFS permissions has changed in Cygwin version 1.7. This might be what's causing the problem.

Try adding the 'noacl' flag to your Cygwin mounts in C:\cygwin\etc\fstab, for example:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive user,noacl,posix=0 0 0
```

You can pass custom permissions via rsync using the 'chmod' option:

```
rsync -rvz --chmod=ugo=rwX -e ssh source destination
```

Comment: --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fgo=r   (755DIRs 644FILEs, the default)

Comment: If you are running independent of a cygwin installation, use the `cygpath` utility to identify the location of the `fstab` to write to with `cygpath -w /etc/fstab`. This will usually be either relative to `%TMP%` or the current directory.

Comment: fwiw none of the `noacl` or `--chmod` suggestions above worked for me. But using `--no-perms` worked.

Comment: No `cygpath` command when installing cwRsync through chocolatery as far as I'm concerned. How to edit dygwin\etc\fstab when it doesn't seem to be installed? 

Comment: @JesusIniesta Did you find out where cwRsync reads fstab? This isn't a full cygwin installation, so I'm wondering the same. Maybe it's just the default C:/cygwin?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem stems from the fact that the Unix permissions on that directory really are 0.  All of the access information is stored in separate ACLs, which rsync does not copy.  Thus, it sets the permissions on the remote copy to 0, and, obviously, is unable to write to that directory afterwards. 
You can run

```
chmod -R 775
```

on that directory, which should fix your rsync problem.

After a look at the manpage I can tell that the chmod param is available in rsync since version ~2.6.8. But you have to use `--chmod=ugo=rwX` in combination with `rsync -av`

You should also try this command:

```
rsync -av <SOURCE_DIR> rsyncuser@192.168.1.110:/srv/www/prj112/myfolder
```

It would work on Linux at least. And note that rsync does not need to mention ssh--at least on Linux.

But if all fails and just to give an option you may take a look at this ready packed-up tool [cwRsync](http://mirror.transact.net.au/sourceforge/s/project/se/sereds/cwRsync/4.1.0/)

Answer (score 7):

if you deploy a site from windows (for ex. octopress use rsync) it's possible set permission to 775 adding multiple chmod command:

```
   rsync -avz --chmod=ug=rwx --chmod=o=rx -e ssh
```

Comment: note this seems to also 755's files, not just directories, which is generally not advised for web hosts.

Answer (score 2):

To rsync from Windows to Unix/Linux you should provide a command like

```
SET BACKUP_SERVER=my.backup.server
SET SSH_USER=theUnixUserName
SET STORAGEPATH=/home/%SSH_USER%/Backup/
SET STORAGEURI=%BACKUP_SERVER%:%STORAGEPATH%    
SET SSH_ID=/cygdrive/c/Users/theWindowsUserName/Documents/keyfiles/id_dsa
SET EXCLUDEFILE=backup_excludes.txt
SET BACKUPLOGFILE=/cygdrive/c/Users/theWindowsUserName/Backuplogs/backup-%DATE%-%TIME::=-%.log
```

The ssh command then is

```
SET BACKUP=rsync -azvu --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fgo=r --rsh="ssh -l %SSH_USER% -i '%SSH_ID%'" --exclude-from=%EXCLUDEFILE% --delete --delete-excluded --log-file="%BACKUPLOGFILE%"
```

with **backup_excludes.txt** containing lines of ignored elements like

```
.git
.svn
.o
\Debug
\Release
```

Then you would use this in a script with

```
%BACKUP% /cygdrive/c/mySensibleData %STORAGEURI%
%BACKUP% /cygdrive/c/myOtherSensibleData %STORAGEURI%
%BACKUP% /cygdrive/c/myOtherSensibleData2 %STORAGEURI%
```

and so on. This will backup your directories **mySensibleData**, **myOtherSensibleData** and **myOtherSensibleData2** with the permissions 755 for directories and 644 for files. You also get backup logs in your **%BACKUPLOGFILE%** for each backup.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin rsync will report permission denied when some process has the target file open. Download and run Process Explorer and find out if anything else is locking the file or simply try renaming the file and see if you get the Windows error about some other process having the file open.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try to create a (global) environment variable `CYGWIN` and set its value to `nontsec`