# rsync (cwrsync) in Gitbash - The source and destination cannot both be remote. [windows 7]

Tags: windows, rsync, git-bash, cwrsync

I am trying to sync a local path to another drive using Git Bash in Windows 7. I downloaded cwRsync and copied the files over to my Git bash bin directory. I can run rsync but the following command gives me problems

> rsync -av /c/00-dev/05-batch /f/RSYNC/
>       The source and destination cannot both be remote.
>       rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1135) [receiver=3.0.6]

Both the paths are correct but it won't sync.

Answer (score 14):

Workaround: `cd` to `/c` and `rsync` using relative paths.

So this works:

```
cd /c
touch temp/test.txt
rsync temp/test.txt temp/test2.txt
```

while this doesn't, even if you `cd` to `/c`:

```
$ rsync /c/temp/test.txt /c/temp/test2.txt
The source and destination cannot both be remote.
```

Tested with the Git Bash that came with `git 2.9.0.windows.1`.

Comment: Nice answer, but it does not work when syncing between different drives.

Answer (score 5):

This works using *cwRsync* from *Git Bash*.

```sh
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
rsync -av /cygdrive/c/00-dev/05-batch /cygdrive/f/RSYNC/
```

[cwRsync.exe](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/rsync) needs `/cygdrive/<drive-letter>` for absolute pathing, so the simple `rsync -av /cygdrive/c/00-dev/05-batch /cygdrive/f/RSYNC/` works from the *cmd*.

However, *Git Bash* converts paths like `.../c/...` to weird things like `...C:\...`. The line: `export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` prevents that conversion. (See more: [How to stop MinGW and MSYS from mangling path names given at the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line)).

Use `unset MSYS_NO_PATHCONV` in the script to restore standard *Git Bash* behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows I tried cwRsync to sync data between folders located on Z:(network disk) and D:(usb stick) excluding a subfolder 'Data':

```
rsync -r -v --size-only --dry-run --exclude=Data --chmod=ugo=rwX /cygdrive/z/"Scan folder"/"Sub folder" /cygdrive/d/"Scan folder"/"Sub folder"
```

**-r** means recursively, **-v** verbose output, **--dry-run** is just for testing (data doesn't transfer), **--exclude** excludes subfolder or file(s), **--chmod=ugo=rwX** sets proper permissions (read more about permissions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5911943) with comments)

For *cyrillic names* on Windows use 'chcp 65001'.

Comment: Nice answer, but it does not work from git-bash, due to the path conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as following:

rsync.exe -avr --chmod=ugo=rwX "//DESKTOP-NQIR1HR/D$/Bkp Google Drive" "//DESKTOP-NQIR1HR/E$/Bkp Google Drive"

Where "DESKTOP-NQIR1HR" is my computer hostname