# Rsync on Windows: cannot access copied folders

Tags: windows, cygwin, rsync

I'm trying to copy files between two **Windows Server** machines.
Have installed cygwin 1.7.23 on both server.
The script is run by the **SYSTEM** user. 
The problem is that the files are no longer accessible when logged in as Administrator user although the permissions were copied, verified using ls -l from cygwin. ("You don't currently have permission to access this folder").

**Important observation:** This problem reproduces only when coping files from **remote** to **local** computer. Coping from **local** to **remote** works.

1. Tried using rsyc with the following options:

   rsync -hrtavpe "ssh"
2. Tried adding default permissions using rsync's chmod option

   --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fog=r
3. Edited the C:\cygwin\etc\fstab file as suggested in this post [1]

Created two folders logged in as SYSTEM user:

- The first one created using rsync is **NOT** accessible (folder_copied_with_rsync).
- The second one is created with mkdir and is accessible (folder_created_manualy)

Output of icalcs (from cmd) and ls -l (from cygwin):

```
C:\NgNMS>icacls folder_copied_with_rsync
folder_copied_with_rsync NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX,W,DC)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(DENY)(W,RD,REA,X,DC)
                         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(Rc,S,RA)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(RX,W,DC)
                         Everyone:(Rc,S,RA)
                         CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                         CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                         Everyone:(OI)(CI)(IO)(Rc,S,RA)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\NgNMS>icacls folder_created_manualy
folder_created_manualy NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX,W,DC)
                       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX,W,DC)
                       BUILTIN\Users:(RX,W,DC)
                       Everyone:(Rc,S,RA)
                       CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                       CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                       BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                       Everyone:(OI)(CI)(IO)(Rc,S,RA)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


ls -l
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM       0 Apr 19 15:00 folder_copied_with_rsync
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Apr 20 11:55 folder_created_manualy
```

[1] [Rsync on Windows: wrong permissions for created directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798807/rsync-on-windows-wrong-permissions-for-created-directoried)

Comment: check with `icacls` the windows ACL permissions and owner.

Comment: Updated my question. The problem seems to be at the Users configuration: BUILTIN\Users:(DENY)(W,RD,REA,X,DC)